# Fitting data with Lmfit

Tags: python, lmfit

I have two sets of data, one for the x axis and the other one for the y axis.

I'd like to make a fit of this data, with Lmfit, using the following definition of the Lèvy distribution.

[image: equation]

I have a constraint on *c* paramter, which means it must be greater than zero.

Below there's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model
from lmfit import Parameters

def Levy(x, c, m):
    sq = np.sqrt(c/(2*np.pi))
    ex = np.exp(-c/(2*(x-m)))
    den = (x-m)**(3/2)
    return (sq*(ex/den))

x =np.array([0.03,0.08,0.13,0.18,0.23,0.28,0.33,0.38,0.43,0.48,0.53,0.58,0.63,0.68,0.73,0.78,0.83,0.88,0.93,0.98,1.03,1.08,1.13,1.18,1.23,1.28,1.33,1.38,1.43,1.48,1.53,1.58,1.63,1.68,1.73,1.78,1.83,1.88,1.93,1.98,2.03,2.08,2.13,2.18,2.23,2.28,2.33,2.38,2.43,2.48,2.53,2.58,2.63,2.68,2.73,2.78,2.83,2.88,2.93,2.98,3.03,3.08,3.13,3.28,3.88])

y = np.array([0.9931429,0.98486193,0.9783219,0.96919757,0.95680234,0.93760247,0.91618782,0.89456217,0.87109068,0.85210239,0.83358852,0.81407275,0.78769989,0.769608,0.73258027,0.71332794,0.68289386,0.65704847,0.62566436,0.60256181,0.57835128,0.5548792,0.53167057,0.50746062,0.48303911,0.45002014,0.4283945,0.40618835,0.38540666,0.36984661,0.34648062,0.3311846,0.30871501,0.29568682,0.28075974,0.2635118,0.25164404,0.23793043,0.22806706,0.21794024,0.2047541,0.1938894,0.18065023,0.16651464,0.15079665,0.14093328,0.1260062,0.1199406,0.11350606,0.1043281,0.09615262,0.08565687,0.07763934,0.07194268,0.0637672,0.05701618,0.04615091,0.03945234,0.03285927,0.03238484,0.0287456,0.0242624,0.01529543,0.00986279,0.00173977])

gmodel = Model(Levy)
params = Parameters()
params.add('c', value=0.2)
params.add('m', value=0)
result3 = gmodel.fit(y, x=x, params=params)

plt.plot(x,y,'bo')
plt.plot(x, result3.best_fit)
plt.show()
```

I have two problems:

- How can I plot the fit for different vaues of *c*?
- The peak of the Lèvy distribution does not reach the peak of the data set plot, even if I change the value of *c*.

Could someone help me, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not misktaken, the µ parameter in the Lévy distribution is position parameter shifting the point where the probability density function starts to be non-null.

Given your data, if a Lévy distribution would describe it well then this parameter would be equal to 0 so we are left with one parameter, the scaling parameter c.

It seems that a Lévy distribution might not be the best probability distribution to describe your data.
I rescaled your data so that the area under the curve would be equal to 1 (as for any probability density function) and plotted it together with the Lévy distribution with various values for c and indeed none seem to describe well your data.

```
f = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
t = np.linspace(0, 4, 500)
for c in [0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 4]:
    ax.plot(t, Levy(t, c, 0), label=r"$c=%s$"%c)

ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")

area_y = sum([(x[i+1]-x[i])*(y[i+1]+y[i])*0.5 for i in range(len(x)-1)])
y_ = y/area_y
ax.plot(x, y_, '.', label="data")

ax.legend()
```

[image: Lévy distribution]

If you want to fit such a function to data with constraints on the parameters you could alternatively use scipy optimize.curve_fit function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I have already fit my data with scipy optimize.curve_fit, and also with other distributions, like Gaussian and Double Gaussian, with constrains on the parameters, but they don't fit well the data for values ​​of x greater than about 3. For this reason I was thinking to the Levy distribution. Can you explain me how have you normalize the data, please? The following two lines of code are not clear to me: `area_y = sum([(x[i+1]-x[i])*(y[i+1]+y[i])*0.5 for i in range(len(x)-1)])` and `y_ = y/area_y`

Comment: Also, in your code didn't you just make the plot of several Levy distributions? I actually would like to use the distribution to make a fit with Lmfit. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes I just plotted several Lévy distribution to show that no good fit could be obtained. If you take c smaller than 0.2 the maximum will be higher but the decrease will be sharper so it won't fit your data. If you take higher values for c it won't fit your data better so even if you fit with Lmfit or any fitting method no good fit can't be obtained.

Comment: And for the normalization I computed the area by summing the area of rectangles whose width is x[i+1]-x[i] and height is (y[i+1]+y[i])*0.5 (mean between the two y values). Then I normalized all y values by this so that the area under the curve is now 1.

Comment: Ok now it's clearer. But I still have some doubts: doing so you are using normalized data, but the equation of the Lèvy function isn't normalized. I'm wrong? Also don't you think that doing a fit maybe I could find a value for the c parameter, such that the fit is closer to the data?

Comment: Ok sorry, the area under a Lèvy distribution is 1, so I've answered myself. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm sorry but I've tried to calculate the area with `a = scipy.integrat.simps(x,y_)`, and it doesn't return me 1. But I've found this other way, that I hope it's correct: `areaData = simps(x, y)`  `y_ = y/areaData`
`area2 = simps(x, y_)` and it returns me 1, but when I have to plot the data, I should write `plt.plot(x, (-y_))`

Comment: You should use `simps(y, x)`, this is why you have negative value for the area. Of course doing `a = scipy.integrat.simps(y_,x)` won't give you exactly 1 but will give you something close to 1. Scipy simps use a different way of measuring the area under the curve.

Comment: Ok, the last question: the Levy distribution has integral equal to 1 if I integrate from -infinity to infinity. If I want the integral to be equal to 1 for x from 0.03 to 3.88, for example, how should I proceed?

Comment: I try to explain my self better: I know that the integral from -infinity to infinity of the Levy distribution is equal to 1 (for all the c values), and the integral from 0.03 and 3.88 of my data set is equal to 1 too (normalized data). But is it right to compare the Levy distribution with my normalized data, or maybe I should write my data so that the integral from -infinity to infinity is equal to 1, instead of the integral from 0.03 to 3.88 equal to 1?

Comment: You data is anyway null outside the range so integrating from -infinity to infinity or on the data range is the same.